# Is there a word for wanting more but when getting it, it’s not enough?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am reading *American Psycho* and trying to compare it with Edgar Allan Poe short stories in which I have to make a question for it Long story short both characters want something (the satisfaction of killing others) but when they get it (killing them) they don’t feel satisfied... I’ve never done this before but yah

Comment: [**insatiable**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/insatiable) *(especially of a desire or need) - **too great to be satisfied**.*

Comment: It's never enough!

Comment: The tag you chose says that your question is about [tag:filler-words]. I don't see the connection with something not being satisfied. Can you please elaborate on your question?

Comment: Since **filler-words** is a fairly obscure tag (with only 26 recorded uses), an edit has been suggested to change the tag to **single-word-requests**, which I feel is much more appropriate.

Comment: Sorry...like I said I’ve never used this before and thought that it wasn’t important..my bad

Answer (score 1):

You can regard such condition as [**insatiability**](https://www.yourdictionary.com/insatiability) (noun).

> **1.** The condition of being insatiable - while [insatiable](https://www.yourdictionary.com/insatiable) is an adjective that denotes: (of an appetite or desire) impossible to satisfy. Note that the word insatiable/insatiability doesn't neccessarily denotes a desire of eating more and more, it can be used to denote other type of desires e.g. of power, of killing people, etc.

**Examples:**

- An example of **insatiability** is a lust of power in any corrupt leader, who never becomes satisfied with what position he has.
- An example of **insatiable** is a desire for more and more money that never goes away.
- An example of **insatiable** is a terrorist who keeps killing the people at bulk, but never becomes satisfied with how many people they have killed.

Answer (score 0):

**unquenchable** [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/216756?redirectedFrom=unquenchable#eid)

> That cannot be overcome, subdued, appeased, or dispelled.

As in:

> But it’s matched by an equally teeming, unquenchable emptiness. Los
>   Angeles Times Jul 18, 2018

and your question:

> After the killings, their criminal lust is still unquenched!